# Transform a Map to List

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to transform the map of the object in json to List using JQ ...

Source:

```
{
  "title": "title",
  "keyword": "keyword",
  "desc": {
    "user1": {
      "name": "kumar",
      "Duration": null,
      "Time": null,
      " Dominance": "Upper Field First"
    },
    "user2": {
      "id": "user2",
      "name": "user2",
      "Duration": null,
      "Time": null,
      " Dominance": "Upper Field First"
    }
  }
}
```

Target:

```
[
  {
    "id": "user1",
    "name": "kumar",
    "Duration": null,
    "Time": null,
    "Dominance": "Upper Field First"
  },
  {
    "id": "user2",
    "name": "user2",
    "Duration": null,
    "Time": null,
    "Dominance": "Upper Field First"
  }
]
```

I tried various options like , but not able to get the extact thing i need.

1. `.desc | . as $in| keys[]`
2. `to_entries`

JQ Workspace ::: https://jqplay.org/s/MiJ9w1Sz5L

Comment: Where does the value for `id` in `user1` come from? The input object doesn't have it.

Comment: And what about the leading blank in `" Dominance"`? Is that real or a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following filter will do what you want, assuming you've fixed the input:

```
.desc
| to_entries
| map( {id: .key} + .value)
```

To understand this, simply read up on `to_entries` in the online manual (see [jq](/questions/tagged/jq)).